# How to authorize via Google API from WebApp with an unknown URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to build a plugin for a WordPress App, that uploads file to the users Google Drive space. I don't want the end user to create the Cloud Console Project. but rather just have him give consent so the plugin can access the needed data from his Google Drive account.

When I create OAuth 2.0 Client IDs in the Google Cloud Console (Web Application), Google asks for Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs. Since the plugin will be portable and can be installed on different websites I can't define this.
How can this be solved that an OAuth2 Authentication by the user can be done, without knowing the URL where the app is running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant.  Redirect uri must be configured properly, to point webserver the code **authorization** is running on.

You will need to instruct your users in how to create their own client.

Also as this is a WordPress application, you would need to share your client id and secret with the users. This is also against googles TOS.

## possible workaround.

If you put up an authorization server on your own server.  The users of your app could then login though that. A refresh token will be returned to their website running your app and stored locally. Your code could then run using the refresh token to access their data.

However you are then going to be responsible for verifying an app with google drive scopes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Several apps seem to be having a solution in place already that works. I believe your workaround is used here: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/integrate-google-drive/tags/1.173/app/class-client.php is this correct?